# How to setup UbuntU Server and Host Website on it?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, webmin

I spent days gathering information from the internet and there is no information on the latest ubuntu on installing, hosting, and creating webhost for it. I was using info from all different articles and trying to put them togeather. My biggest problem is trying to connect to the website through webmin, it just kept connecting to my router instead of the server. Does anyone have a good tutotal out there for latest ubuntu or a full tutorial on a webhost and pointing the domain to it?

Comment: Like you say, your serer is behind router. You must do port forwarding. Port 80 is for http.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Traffic from internet go first to your router, after that router look in routing able and in nat table. If you wish to access web server on local network with addr 192.168.1.100 you must do port forwarding on router for packet from internet with destination port 80 to 192.168.1.100.

Comment: After I setup the port forward, What do I point my domain to?

Comment: Public ip address. You get public ip address on wan port of router in most cases.

Comment: fixed it, needed to port foward my computer